# How do we show inverse relationship while converting parametric equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, coordinate-systems, locus

Good Day

Suppose we have to convert parametric equation $(\cos t, \sin t)$ into cartesian equation.
We realize that $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1$, so $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Sorry, if I ask, but I don't understand that when doing this, every parametric point lies on the graph of the equation, but how do we show that *every* point on the graph of the equation can be represented as a parametric point (i.e. there are no "extra" points on the graph)?

This is a relatively simpler example. For example, how do we show that every point on $(x + y - 7) ^ 2 + (x - y + 1)^ 2 = 100$ can be represented as a parametric form $(5 \cos t + 5 \sin t + 3, 5 \cos t - 5 \sin t + 4)$ for some $t$?

Answer (score 2):

Quite often, the parametric equations will **not** produce all the points of the graph. Or, saying this another way, the graph will contain “extra” points besides those generated by the parametric equations.

A very simple example: suppose the given parametric equations are $x=\sin(t)$ and $y= \sin(t)$. Then obviously every point generated by these equations lies on the line $y=x$. But it’s also obvious that $x(t) \le 1$ and $y(t) \le 1$ for all values of $t$, so there are many points on the line $y=x$ that are not “covered” by the parametric equations. The point $(x,y) = (7,7)$, for example.

In general, suppose we’re given parametric equations $x=u(t)$ and $y= v(t)$. We may be able to find a function $F:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $F(u(t), v(t)) = 0$ for all $t$. This shows that the curve generated by the parametric equations lies within the set $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : F(x,y)= 0 \}$. But to show that the curve covers all of $S$ we have to show that for any given point $(a,b) \in S$ there exists a parameter value $t$ such that $u(t)=a$ and $v(t) = b$. This is often not easy to do.